# Can I select a group of tables to format in microsoft word using VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm looking for a way to quickly format groups of tables in documents. Unfortunately I can't just format all tables as I have to leave some unmodified (usually in the appendices, but sometimes at the beginning).

What I have so far will allow me to format all tables from Table 4 to the end. I can't figure out how to select tables 4 through 78 for example. I also need all of the cells to be vertically oriented in the middle. I've spent an ungodly amount of my life formatting each individual table, so any help would be GREATLY APPRECIATED.

```
Sub FormatTables()

Dim TableIndex As Long
Dim Mytable As Table

For TableIndex = 4 To ActiveDocument.tables.Count
    Set Mytable = ActiveDocument.tables(TableIndex)
    With Mytable
        .Range.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("TableText Arial 9")
        .PreferredWidthType = wdPreferredWidthPercent
        .PreferredWidth = 100
        .Rows.Alignment = wdAlignRowCenter
        .Rows.Height = InchesToPoints(0)
        .TopPadding = InchesToPoints(0)
        .BottomPadding = InchesToPoints(0)
        .LeftPadding = InchesToPoints(0.08)
        .RightPadding = InchesToPoints(0.08)
        .Spacing = 0
        .AllowPageBreaks = True
        .AutoFitBehavior (wdAutoFitWindow)
    End With
Next TableIndex

End Sub
```

Comment: `ActiveDocument.Tables.Count`...you would need to change that, right?

Comment: Do you mean by changing your `For TableIndex = 4 to ActiveDocument.Tables.Count` to stop somewhere sooner? (BTW, you should learn to properly indent your code. It makes it much easier to see the flow of execution if you can easily tell where blocks begin and end.)

Comment: yes! I need it to stop somewhere sooner and not go all the way to the end of the document. I’m not even sure if Table.index is the best way to do this. 

Sorry I’m new to this!

Comment: Read the line of code that's been pointed out to you twice now. How would you change `For TableIndex = 4 to ActiveDocument.Tables.Count` to stop sooner? Maybe by stopping somewhere else than `ActiveDocument.Tables.Count`, right? So how do you suppose you could do that? You need to read and understand the code you're using.

Comment: Got it. Can’t believe I missed that earlier. Any idea about how to fix the vertical orientation of the cells?

Comment: That would be a totally separate question, which belongs in another post.

Comment: What do you mean by 'I also need all of the cells to be vertically oriented in the middle'? The code already applies vertical centering. See my updated answer for applying horizontal centering as well.

Comment: Strangely enough not all of the content in the tables is centered vertically in the cell. The code is nearly perfect except for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example:

```
Sub FormatTables()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim TableIndex As Long
For TableIndex = 4 To 78
  With ActiveDocument.Tables(TableIndex)
    .Range.Style = "TableText Arial 9"
    .PreferredWidthType = wdPreferredWidthPercent
    .PreferredWidth = 100
    .Rows.Alignment = wdAlignRowCenter
    'Format the paragraphs centrally as well
    '.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
    .Rows.Height = 0
    .TopPadding = 0
    .BottomPadding = 0
    .LeftPadding = InchesToPoints(0.08)
    .RightPadding = InchesToPoints(0.08)
    .Spacing = 0
    .AllowPageBreaks = True
    .AutoFitBehavior (wdAutoFitWindow)
    End With
Next TableIndex
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete `Set Mytable = ActiveDocument.tables(TableIndex)` from your procedure.
2. Delete `Dim Mytable As Table` from your procedure.
3. Replace your procedure's declaration line with `Private Sub FormatTable(Mytable As Table)` (singular "table" in the name).
4. Create a new procedure as shown below.

Here:

```
Sub FormatTables()    ' plural "tables"

    Dim i As Integer
    
    For i = 4 To 78
        FormatTable ActiveDocument.Tables(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Note that tables are indexed in the order of their appearance. If you insert a table the index of all tables below the insertion changes. If this is an issue in your project you may assign names to the tables using the `Title` property. You can then address individual tables by their titles.