# How can I vertically align all cells of certain tables in word?

Tags: vba, ms-word, format

I'm trying to format multiple (but not all) tables in a document. I've been able to adjust everything except cell vertical alignment which I want to be centered.

Here is an example of a resulting table after running the code.
[Table Result][1]

Here is the code I've been using :

````
Sub FormatTables()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim TableIndex As Long
For TableIndex = 4 To 75
  With ActiveDocument.tables(TableIndex)
    .Range.Style = "TableText Arial 9"
    .PreferredWidthType = wdPreferredWidthPercent
    .PreferredWidth = 100
    .Rows.Alignment = wdAlignRowCenter
    .Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
    .Rows.Height = 0
    .TopPadding = 0
    .BottomPadding = 0
    .LeftPadding = InchesToPoints(0.08)
    .RightPadding = InchesToPoints(0.08)
    .Spacing = 0
    .AllowPageBreaks = True
    .AutoFitBehavior (wdAutoFitWindow)
    End With
Next TableIndex
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub```


This is  a continuation of a previously answered question <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65947672/can-i-select-a-group-of-tables-to-format-in-microsoft-word-using-vba>.


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qD5j.png

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
````

Answer (score 0):

The lines:

```
.Rows.Alignment = wdAlignRowCenter
.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
```

already vertically and horizontally center every cell's contents, respectively. Have you checked the paragraph before/after space settings? Perhaps you need to change:

```
.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
```

to:

```
With .Range.ParagraphFormat
    .Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
    .LineSpacingRule = wdLineSpaceSingle
    .SpaceBefore = 0
    .SpaceAfter = 0
End With
```

To loop through all the cells to do the vertical alignment you could use code like:

```
Dim c As Cell
With .Range
  For c = 1 To .Cells.Count
    .Cells(c).VerticalAlignment = wdCellAlignVerticalCenter
  Next
End With
```

instead of:

```
.Rows.Alignment = wdAlignRowCenter
```

Comment: Still nothing. I think it has something to do with the author setting the actual cells to be vertically aligned. Any other ideas?

Comment: I should clarify - the macro is run after all editorial changes have been made. It is also applied to the intended tables. I believe that this is the property that needs to be changed: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.cell.verticalalignment I just don't know how to incorporate it into my code.

Comment: Using '.Rows.Alignment = wdAlignRowCenter' - which is already in the code - does exactly the same as looping through all the cells and using 'Cell.Alignment = wdAlignRowCenter'. Another possibility is that some cells aren't using single line spacing. See my updated answer. Ultimately, we're playing a guessing game here because you haven't told us how the cells are formatted...

Comment: Happy to share with you what I can. Right now, the only way for me to fix the alignment of the cells is to go to Table Properties, Cell, and change the vertical alignment from Top to Middle. I've confirmed that single line spacing is used throughout. I've also run a really simple code on one of the tables to see if it fixed the spacing and it did not. `Sub test()
 ActiveDocument.tables(4).Rows(1) _
 .Alignment = wdAlignRowCenter
End Sub` Any wisdom about how to access individual cells to be able to use the cell.Alignment  in my code?